# How to complete a Sign-In-With-Slac-cycle as a Slack bot user?

Tags: oauth, bots, slack, slack-api

Even though the slack API docs are very well made and specifically authentication follows the oAuth standards very well I am trapped in a bit of a corner case that I am unsure if it can be solved.

### Normal Sign in as Slack

In my case an app exists that makes use of Slack as an oAuth provider. So people sign in into that 3rd party app using Slacks oAuth provider ([Sign in with slack](https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack)).

Now this usually creates a regular oAuth flow with a human user being redirect to Slack and signing in there and then coming back to the app with a token that is exchanged into another token.

### What I would like to achieve

Now I do have a not a regular bot a "Bot user" within slack and I would like to sign in into the 3rd party app on behalf of that bot user instead of being a normal user.

So in theory I would need to complete the oAuth journey with being validated as the bot user and then having slack return a validation token the app that will be resolved to a session of the bot user.

*Does anyone see this as something being possible?*

Comment: I don't quite remember the specifics, but I think I accomplished this by restricting scopes to bot-only. When authorizing (utilizing my user account), it was clearly indicated that I was only authorizing the bot user and subsequent calls were indeed sent from the bot.

Comment: Thanks for taking a go on this @Diego Does that mean you were able to choose which user you are authorizing for while using the flow? So could you switch from normal user to bot account?

I mean even that would not be enough for me. I need the bot to be able to do the login flow on the backend-to-backend channel itself. So that no human interaction is necessary.